# Delete Magento 2 product custom option programmatically

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I created magento 2 custom option programmatically like this:

```
    $options[] = [
                        'title' => 'cthulu',
                        'type' => 'field',
                        'is_require' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 2,
                        'price' => 0,
                        'price_type' => 'fixed',
                        'sku' => 'cthulu',
                        'max_characters' => 20,
                    ];

    $options[] = [
                        'title' => 'comment',
                        'type' => 'field',
                        'is_require' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 2,
                        'price' => 0,
                        'price_type' => 'fixed',
                        'sku' => 'comment',
                        'max_characters' => 50,
                    ];

foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $customOption = $this->customOptionFactory->create(['data' => $option]);
                    $customOption->setProductSku($product->getSku());
                    $customOptions[] = $customOption;
                }

                $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true)
                ->setOptions($customOptions)
                ->setHasOptions(true)
                ->save();
```

the custom option save successfully, now i want to delete the custom option programmatically, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

To simply remove all the custom options from all products 
use the below one time script.
Add it in any of your controller.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $products = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
            if ($product->getOptions()) {
                foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt) {
                    $opt->delete();
                }
                //$product->setHasOptions(0)->save();
            } else {
                echo $product->getId();
            }
        }
        echo 'DONE';
```

This is one time hitting script, so no need for not **using Object Manager**

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    namespace Test\Module\Block;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

    class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
     {

          protected $productRepository; 

          public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
          ) {
              parent::__construct($context);

              $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
          }
}
```

now you can delete option like,

`$product = $this->productRepository->getById(1);`// replace with your product Id

```
if($product->getOptions() != ”){
       foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt){
                   $opt->delete();
               }
       $product->setHasOptions(0)->save();
  }
```

Comment: why i need to setHasOptions to 0?

Comment: Because you are deleting all your product option @Hunter